# Change which select gets displayed based on another select option, and maintain same option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a product page that has three select options:

- Fit
- Colour
- Size

By default, the 'Fit' dropdown and 'Colour' dropdown are active with a default value selected (e.g. Regular Fit and Red Colour).

The 'Size' dropdown needs to change depending on what is selected in the 'Fit' dropdown. For example, if a 'Petite' fit
 is selected then the appropriate dropdown for 'Size' with petite sizes is displayed. If the user then decides to select a 'Long' fit then the appropriate dropdown for 'Size' with long sizes is displayed.

I have two problems:

1. By default, the "Size" dropdown doesn't appear due to the script I'm using (see code snippet below). It only appears after you select a new value from the "fit" dropdown.
2. Ideally I would like the same 'Size' value to be maintained as the user selects a different 'Fit'. For example, if a Regular Fit in Size 10 is selected and the user selects a Petite Fit, at the moment the initial value is '- Choose Size -'. I would like it to pass the value of 10 to the new dropdown instead so the user doesn't have to select the size again. (**answered by zack-w** https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290039/7331363)

So far I have the following code on jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dodgers76/c0dvdwbz/

```
$(function(){
var sizeVal = 'none';

  $("select.selector-fit").on("change", function(){
    //remove active
    $("select.selector-sizes.active").removeClass("active");
    //check if select class exists. If it does then show it
    var subList = $("select.selector-sizes."+$(this).val());
    if (subList.length){
      //class exists. Show it by adding active class to it
      subList.addClass("active");
      subList.val(sizeVal);
    }
  });

  $('.selector-sizes').on('change', function() {
    sizeVal = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to change in regards to issue #1

Comment: Hi @jonmrich, when I first load the page, I would like all three dropdowns to be visible with the following defaults; Fit = "Regular", Colour = "Red", Size = "Choose Size". At the moment it only displays Fit and Colour on initial load. The "Size" dropdown only appears if you choose another option under "Fit". https://jsfiddle.net/dodgers76/c0dvdwbz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make the current selected size value a variable if you want to share it between the different size selects.

```
var sizeVal = 'none';

$('.selector-sizes').on('change', function() {
    sizeVal = $(this).val();
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61q22umo/25/)

### EDIT

You can add the `value` attribute to the select options so that the value matches regardless of the text `<option value="20">20 (not available)</option>`

[Here is the updated JSFiddle for your edit](https://jsfiddle.net/c0dvdwbz/7/)

Look at how I changed the `<option>` for all size 20s

Comment: Hi @zack-w thanks for the code. This is just what I needed. I accidentally posted an old jsfiddle link in my original post but I've updated it now. In some of the size dropdowns there are some values that have additional text such as "not available" or "out of stock" (e.g. under Fit = Petite, Size 10 = Out of Stock. Due to the extra text, if I go from Petite 10 to Long 10, the values are different and the dropdown remains blank. Is there a way around this by keeping the additional text?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this site, but your answer has been ticked. Thanks again.